# How do I add field like street,city,country, Region etc. in DataKind tag in Contact.xml.

Tags: android, xml

I am making contact app of mine in that i am adding contact to my specific account.I used common functionality such as normal contact apps have i.e syncing,insertion,deletion, etc. ,I used file name "contact.xml" in my project's xml folder 
the link is here :http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2_r1/packages/apps/Contacts/tests/res/xml/test_basic_contacts.xml?av=f
 but now want to modify this in my adreess tag.
**So my question is : How do I add field like street,city,country, Region etc. in DataKind tag in Contact.xml.**